# What should i do to loop my javascript code in every id's in my table

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table that will show the reserved customers and will countdown the remaining date/time before they arrived. How can i make my javascript loop to get every id's arrival_date and arrival_time?

This is for my capstone thesis, i'm trying to learn ajax to loop it in my php, but i want to know if there's is another way to loop it.

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i>Data Table Example</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Promo ID</th>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Contact number</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Arrival Date</th>
                            <th>Arrival Time</th>
                            <th>Masahista</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>

                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    include'dbcon.php';
                    $user_query=mysql_query("select * from reservation")or 
                    die(mysql_error());
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
                    $id=$row['reserve_id']; ?>
                        <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['reserve_id']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['promo_code']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['contact_number']; ?> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['gender']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['arrival_date']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['arrival_time']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['masahista']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id='<?php echo $row[' reserve_id '];?>'></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $row['arrival_date']; ?> <?php 
    echo $row['arrival_time']; ? > ").getTime();
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *
    60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['reserve_id']; ?>").innerHTML =
    days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['reserve_id']; ?>").innerHTML =
    "EXPIRED";
    }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

I expect the script to loop to every id's to get the value of every id

Comment: Okay, you're saying what you _expect_, now what is the actual result?

Comment: An indented code is more pleasant to read. (did I say readable?)

Comment: By the way, there is no ajax.

Comment: @PatrickQ The result is its getting the value of the first id only

Comment: @Cid Don't know how to properly ask a question with a code cause its my first time to ask here.

Comment: @Cid But i'm watching AJAX Tutorial right now?

Comment: 4 spaces are great for indenting. And no, there is no ajax call in your code.

Comment: @Cid ow cause im still learning how  to do ajax, but i'm asking if there's any other possible way to make it loop other than using ajax

Answer (score 0):

While echoing the data in php create different ids for each tags using a loop like info-1, info-2, info-3 etc and get the texts of each tags using javascript or jquery using loop in the same way to get all the echoed ids.